# Navegar una lista ul con el teclado arriba y abajo y seleccionar

Tags: javascript

Estoy buscando la manera de navegar la lista `li` y seleccionar con enter, pero no logro aún.

Cuando la lista `opciones` esta desplegado, no puedo lograr la navegación con el teclado.

Necesito navegar y seleccionar un `li` para que luego se cierre `opciones`. El código que tengo es lo único que me imagino hacer.

```js
const miSelect = document.querySelector(".grupo-btn .select");
const opciones = document.getElementById("opciones");
const selecto = document.querySelector(".selecto");

function yoSelect() {

if(!opciones.classList.contains("activo")) {
    
    opciones.classList.add("activo");
    miSelect.classList.add("activo");

    document.addEventListener("click", function() {
        opciones.classList.remove("activo");
        miSelect.classList.remove("activo");
    },{once:true, capture:true});
}

function opcionFuera() {
    opciones.classList.remove("activo");
    miSelect.classList.remove("activo");
}

miSelect.addEventListener("focusout", opcionFuera);
selecto.addEventListener("mouseleave", opcionFuera);
};

window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const opciones = document.getElementById("opciones");
  let activo = opciones.classList.contains("activo");
  const active = document.querySelector("#opciones .opcion");

  if (e.key == "ArrowUp" && activo) {

    console.log("arriba");

    if (active.length != 0) {
      active.classList.remove("activo");
      active.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    } else {
      active = document.getElementById("#opciones").first(".opcion");
    }

    active.nextElementSibling.classList.add("activo");

  }

  if (e.key == "ArrowDown" && activo) {

    console.log("abajo");

    if (active.length != 0) {
      active.classList.remove("activo");
      active.parentNode.previusElementSibling;
    } else {
      active = document.getElementById("#opciones").last(".opcion");
    }

    active.previousElementSibling.classList.add("activo");
  }

});

miSelect.addEventListener("click", yoSelect);
miSelect.addEventListener("focusin", yoSelect);
```

```css
.formulario-user {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: calc(100% - 115px);
  padding: 0 5px
}

.grupo-form,
.grupo-btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

.grupo-form {
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey
}

.grupo-form:hover,
.grupo-form.activo {
  border-bottom-color: green
}

.grupo-btn {
  align-items: center
}

.grupo-form label {
  cursor: pointer
}

.grupo-form label,
.grupo-btn .yo-bi {
  color: grey;
  transition: .3s
}

.grupo-form:hover label,
.grupo-form.activo label,
.grupo-btn:hover .yo-bi,
.grupo-form.activo .yo-bi {
  color: green
}

.grupo-form.error label,
.grupo-form.error .yo-bi {
  color: brown
}

.grupo-btn .selecto {
  display: block;
  position: relative
}

.grupo-btn .select .titulo {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%
}

.grupo-btn .select:hover,
.grupo-btn .select.activo {
  background-color: lightgreen
}

.grupo-btn .select .contenido-select {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: .90rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: "000
}

.grupo-btn.contraseña .btn {
  width: 50%
}

.grupo-btn .opciones {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 145px;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: .10rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: scale(0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, .5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px)
}

.grupo-btn .opciones.activo {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: fadeIn .20s forwards
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
transform: translateY(50%) scale(0)
  }
  to {
transform: translateY(0) scale(1)
  }
}

.opciones .opcion {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .30rem .30rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .80rem
}

.opciones .opcion:hover,
.opciones .opcion.activo {
  color: green;
  background-color: red
}

.grupo-btn .select .contenido-select img,
.grupo-btn .opciones .opcion img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.formInput-info {
  position: absolute;
  right: .50rem;
  color: var(--colorRojo);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .3s
}

.grupo-form.error .formInput-info {
  opacity: 1
}

.grupo-btn .btn,
.btn-sm::-webkit-file-upload-button,
.btn-sm::file-selector-button,
.grupo-btn .opciones .opcion {
  border: 0;
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="formulario-user" id="formulario-user">

  <div class="grupo-form">
    <label for="nombreUser">Nombre para el perfil</label>
    <div class="grupo-btn">
      <span class="yo-bi bi-person-fill"></span>
      <input type="text" class="btn btn-sm" placeholder="nombre">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grupo-form">
    <label for="select">Número de teléfono</label>
    <div class="grupo-btn">
      <span class="yo-bi bi-phone-fill"></span>

      <div class="selecto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm select" id="miTelefono">
                        <span class="titulo bi-chevron-up bi-r-5"> Seleccionar... </span>
                    </button>
        <div class="opciones" id="opciones">
          <div class="opcion" valor="986 234 123">
            <img src="fotoPerfil/Narciso.jpg">
            <span>Paraguay +595</span>
          </div>
          <div class="opcion">
            <img src="img/spain.png" alt="">
            <span class="titulo">España 3656</span>
          </div>
          <div class="opcion">
            <img src="img/colombia.png" alt="">
            <span class="titulo">Colombia 4574</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <input type="tel" class="btn btn-sm" id="formTelefono" placeholder=" número">
    </div>
    <p class="aviso" id="infoTelefono"></p>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: tiene que ser con div? esta funcionalidad viene por defecto si usas  la etiqueta html `select`

Comment: Estoy usando la etiqueta ul li para tener un select personalizado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías definir una opción que tenga la clase 'activo' por defecto (la primera puse en este caso) y que después al usar las arrowkeys uses ese elemento activo como referencia para moverte por las opciones, si pulsas 'arriba' vas a la opcion previa a no ser que estes en el primer elemento en cuyo caso te mueves hacia el ultimo. Al pulsar 'abajo' pasaría exactamente lo contrario.

Quito la clase 'activo' a las opciones que tengan la pseudoclase *:hover* activa y controlo ese estado con el evento 'mouseenter', ya que al seleccionar por teclado y despues pasar el mouse por encima tenia 2 opciones activas. Tambien prevengo que la pagina haga scroll al presionar las arrowkeys con la lista de opciones desplegada:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {

  const opciones = document.getElementById("opciones");
  let activo = opciones.classList.contains("activo");
  let active = document.querySelector(".opcion.activo");

  if (e.key == "ArrowUp" && activo) {
    e.preventDefault() // prevengo scroll
    active.classList.toggle('activo') // quitamos la clase activo al elemento que actualmente lo posea
    active = active.previousElementSibling || active.parentNode.lastElementChild // active ahora es el elemento previo, y si no existe seleccionamos el ultimo
    active.classList.toggle('activo') // agregamos la clase al nuevo active
  } else if(e.key == "ArrowDown" && activo) { // hacemos lo contrario con la tecla abajo
    e.preventDefault()
    active.classList.toggle('activo')
    active = active.nextElementSibling || active.parentNode.firstElementChild
    active.classList.toggle('activo')
  }
});

const listaopciones = document.getElementsByClassName('opcion'); // seleccionamos todas las opciones

for(const opc of listaopciones) { // para cada opcion
  opc.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => { // al entrar el cursor
    let active = document.querySelector(".opcion.activo"); // seleccionamos la opcion activa
    active.classList.toggle('activo') // le quitamos la clase 'activo'
    active = e.target // active ahora es la opcion que disparo el evento
    active.classList.toggle('activo') // le agregamos la clase 'activo' al nuevo active
  })
}
```

CSS (pseudoclase eliminada)

```
/*.opciones .opcion:hover,*/
.opciones .opcion.activo {
  color: green;
  background-color: red
}
```

HTML (agregado elemento seleccionado por defecto)

```
 <div class="opcion activo" valor="986 234 123">
    <img src="fotoPerfil/Narciso.jpg">
    <span>Paraguay +595</span>
 </div>
```

El codigo mostrado solo contiene los cambios mostrados, puedes probarlo completo [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/xje42pcn/). La lista desplegada la posicione por debajo para así visualizarla mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que sería más fácil si usas un elemento `<select>` pero respondiendo directo a tu pregunta creo que puedes hacerlo así (agregué atributos 'data' para los valores en tus opciones):

```js
      const miSelect = document.querySelector('.grupo-btn .select')
      const opciones = document.getElementById('opciones')
      const selecto = document.querySelector('.selecto')

      function yoSelect() {
        if (!opciones.classList.contains('activo')) {
          opciones.classList.add('activo')
          miSelect.classList.add('activo')

          document.addEventListener(
            'click',
            function () {
              opciones.classList.remove('activo')
              miSelect.classList.remove('activo')
            },
            { once: true, capture: true }
          )
        }

        function opcionFuera() {
          opciones.classList.remove('activo')
          miSelect.classList.remove('activo')
        }

        miSelect.addEventListener('focusout', opcionFuera)
        selecto.addEventListener('mouseleave', opcionFuera)
      }

      window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        const opciones = document.getElementById('opciones')
        const activo = opciones.classList.contains('activo')
        const opcion = opciones.querySelector('.opcion.elegida')

        if (e.key == 'ArrowUp' && activo) {
          console.log('arriba')

          // Si hay una opción elegida...
          if (opcion) {
            // ...y hay opciones antes
            if (opcion.previousElementSibling) {
              // quitamos la seleccion
              opcion.classList.remove('elegida')
              // y elegimos la anterior
              opcion.previousElementSibling.classList.add('elegida')
            }
          } else {
            // si no hay nada seleccionado, elegimos el último elemento de la lista
            opciones.lastElementChild.classList.add('elegida')
          }
        }

        if (e.key == 'ArrowDown' && activo) {
          console.log('abajo')

          // Si hay una opción elegida...
          if (opcion) {
            // ...y hay opciones después
            if (opcion.nextElementSibling) {
              // quitamos la seleccion
              opcion.classList.remove('elegida')
              // y elegimos la anterior
              opcion.nextElementSibling.classList.add('elegida')
            }
          } else {
            // si no hay nada seleccionado, elegimos el primer elemento de la lista
            opciones.firstElementChild.classList.add('elegida')
          }
        }

        // Necesitas guardar el valor al presionar Enter
        if (e.key == 'Enter' && activo) {
          const valor = opcion.dataset.valor
          console.log(`Enter, valor ${valor}`)
          // Aquí va tu código para usar el valor en algún sitio
        }
      })

      miSelect.addEventListener('click', yoSelect)
      miSelect.addEventListener('focusin', yoSelect)
```

```css
      .formulario-user {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 300px;
        height: calc(100% - 115px);
        padding: 0 5px
      }

      .grupo-form,
      .grupo-btn {
        display: inline-flex;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%
      }

      .grupo-form {
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        border-bottom: 2px solid grey
      }

      .grupo-form:hover,
      .grupo-form.activo {
        border-bottom-color: green
      }

      .grupo-btn {
        align-items: center
      }

      .grupo-form label {
        cursor: pointer
      }

      .grupo-form label,
      .grupo-btn .yo-bi {
        color: grey;
        transition: .3s
      }

      .grupo-form:hover label,
      .grupo-form.activo label,
      .grupo-btn:hover .yo-bi,
      .grupo-form.activo .yo-bi {
        color: green
      }

      .grupo-form.error label,
      .grupo-form.error .yo-bi {
        color: brown
      }

      .grupo-btn .selecto {
        display: block;
        position: relative
      }

      .grupo-btn .select .titulo {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100%
      }

      .grupo-btn .select:hover,
      .grupo-btn .select.activo {
        background-color: lightgreen
      }

      .grupo-btn .select .contenido-select {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: .90rem;
        pointer-events: none;
        color: "000
      }

      .grupo-btn.contraseña .btn {
        width: 50%
      }

      .grupo-btn .opciones {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 0;
        max-width: 145px;
        max-height: 250px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: .10rem;
        overflow-y: auto;
        transform: scale(0);
        background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, .5);
        backdrop-filter: blur(2px)
      }

      .grupo-btn .opciones.activo {
        transform: scale(1);
        animation: fadeIn .20s forwards
      }

      @keyframes fadeIn {
        from {
      transform: translateY(50%) scale(0)
        }
        to {
      transform: translateY(0) scale(1)
        }
      }

      .opciones .opcion {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100%;
        padding: .30rem .30rem;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: .80rem
      }

      .opciones .opcion:hover,
      .opciones .opcion.elegida {
        color: green;
        background-color: red
      }

      .grupo-btn .select .contenido-select img,
      .grupo-btn .opciones .opcion img {
        width: 20px;
        height: 15px;
        object-fit: cover;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: 5px
      }

      .formInput-info {
        position: absolute;
        right: .50rem;
        color: var(--colorRojo);
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: .3s
      }

      .grupo-form.error .formInput-info {
        opacity: 1
      }

      .grupo-btn .btn,
      .btn-sm::-webkit-file-upload-button,
      .btn-sm::file-selector-button,
      .grupo-btn .opciones .opcion {
        border: 0;
        color: #000
      }
```

```html
    <form action="#" class="formulario-user" id="formulario-user">
      <div class="grupo-form">
        <label for="nombreUser">Nombre para el perfil</label>
        <div class="grupo-btn">
          <span class="yo-bi bi-person-fill"></span>
          <input type="text" class="btn btn-sm" placeholder="nombre" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grupo-form">
        <label for="select">Número de teléfono</label>
        <div class="grupo-btn">
          <span class="yo-bi bi-phone-fill"></span>

          <div class="selecto">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm select" id="miTelefono">
              <span class="titulo bi-chevron-up bi-r-5"> Seleccionar... </span>
            </button>
            <div class="opciones" id="opciones">
              <div class="opcion" data-valor="595">
                <img src="fotoPerfil/Narciso.jpg" />
                <span>Paraguay +595</span>
              </div>
              <div class="opcion" data-valor="3656">
                <img src="img/spain.png" alt="" />
                <span class="titulo">España 3656</span>
              </div>
              <div class="opcion" data-valor="4574">
                <img src="img/colombia.png" alt="" />
                <span class="titulo">Colombia 4574</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <input type="tel" class="btn btn-sm" id="formTelefono" placeholder=" número" />
        </div>
        <p class="aviso" id="infoTelefono"></p>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

He mantenido tu estructura, pero sería importante que utilices nombres diferentes para las propiedades `id` y `class`, ya que tienen usos diferentes dentro del DOM.

### CSS

He considerado quitar el efecto `hover` debido a la lógica comentada que indica que la interacción se realiza a través de las flechas.

```
.opciones .opcion.activo {
    color: green;
    background-color: red
}
```

### HTML

```
<ul class="opciones" id="opciones">
    <li class="opcion" valor="986 234 123">
        <img src="fotoPerfil/Narciso.jpg">
        <span>Paraguay +595</span>
    </li>
    <li class="opcion">
        <img src="img/spain.png" alt="">
        <span class="titulo">España 3656</span>
    </li>
    <li class="opcion">
        <img src="img/colombia.png" alt="">
        <span class="titulo">Colombia 4574</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### JS

```
const KEY_CODE_UP = 38;
const KEY_CODE_DOWN = 40;
const KEY_CODE_ENTER = 13;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const selectButton = document.querySelector(".selecto button.select");
    const opciones = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul#opciones li.opcion"));
    const keyCodes = [KEY_CODE_UP, KEY_CODE_DOWN, KEY_CODE_ENTER];
    
    if(!selectButton.classList.contains('activo') || opciones.length === 0) return;

    if(!keyCodes.includes(event.keyCode)) return;

    const indexActivo = opciones.findIndex(li => li.classList.contains('activo'));
    const lastIndex = opciones.length - 1;
    if(indexActivo == -1){
        const index = event.keyCode === KEY_CODE_UP ? lastIndex : 0;
        addActivo(opciones, index);
        return;
    }

    switch(event.keyCode){
        case KEY_CODE_UP:
            let upIndex = indexActivo == 0 ? lastIndex : indexActivo - 1;
            addActivo(opciones, upIndex);
            break;
        case KEY_CODE_DOWN:
            let downIndex = indexActivo == lastIndex ? 0 : indexActivo + 1;
            addActivo(opciones, downIndex);
            break;
        case KEY_CODE_ENTER:
            const liActivo = opciones.find(li => li.classList.contains('activo'));
            // TODO
            break;
    }
});

function addActivo(opciones, index){
    opciones.map(li => li.classList.remove('activo'));
    opciones[index].classList.add('activo');
}
```